# Rename "trains" tag to "rail"?

Tags: discussion, support, tagging

I've noticed a couple of questions about train stations in the past few days and we don't really have an appropriate tag though obviously they're going to be a pretty important travel topic.

Most questions about stations have also been about trains so using the [trains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trains) tag was obvious. But some questions are only about the stations and don't mention trains at all.

I propose broadening the [trains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trains) to [rail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rail) so that it will also include stations regardless of whether or not trains are also part of the question.

Comment: I'm in two minds.

On the one hand, there are plenty of questions about trains which are not about stations.  In this case, [tag:stations] is nice and separate from [tag:trains].

You're saying when there's a question about a train station, we should use [tag:stations] and [tag:rail] or just [tag:rail]? Don't we lose some granularity this way?

Comment: Why on earth would separating `stations` from `trains` be "nice"? So you could also use the former for cattle stations and radio stations? We don't need a `stations` tag - we only need a `rail` tag because that inherently, historically, and unexceptionally covers stations, trains, engines, cabooses, tracks, platforms, engineers, different guages, and Thomas the Tank d-;

Comment: Because some questions are about trains, and other questions are about stations? We have planes and airports as separate too...

Comment: We have questions about squat toilets and modern Japanese toilets too. Should we split the `toilet-usage` tag? I really don't get what the benefit you see could possibly be. People interested in train station questions getting annoyed at all the non-station train questions in their inbox?? `\-:`

Comment: Strawman! No, my point being if there's a question about planes, it doesn't get stuck with all the questions about heathrow airport.  Similarly there's no need to stick all the questions about say, platzkart travel on trains with question on opening hours of Kings Cross station.

Comment: Normally I'd recommend adding new specific tags when some topic actually gets a number of questions. Then I would actually recommend making a new tag for each specific train station that applies to, if it happens, how many questions about stations / Kings Cross station do we have?

Comment: If we wanted to go with the planes analogy we would need `air-travel` => `rail-travel`, `airports` => `train-stations`, `aircraft` => `trains`, then we have a tag for each airline and each major aircraft builder. I think that's mostly pragmatic except for the manufacturers, but I don't think splitting up train stuff is as pragmatic.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** Don't change.

---

If by *stations* in "some questions are only about the stations and don't mention trains at all" you mean specifically train stations IMO then [trains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trains) is good enough for both. On the basis that there can't be many train stations whose existence is not justified in some way by trains. Also, there can't be many trains that run terminus to terminus without intermediate stops (though I acknowledge the likes of LGW's inter-terminal shuttle) - though for them *stations* (intermediate rather then termini) woud not apply anyway. The point I am trying to make is that trains and stations are too closely related to be worth separating for TSE.

Related tags currently in use include:

[amtrak](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amtrak)
[china-railway](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china-railway)
[deutsche-bahn](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deutsche-bahn)
[eurail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eurail)
[eurostar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eurostar)
[high-speed-rail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-speed-rail)
[indian-railways](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-railways)
[interrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interrail)
[japan-rail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan-rail)
[jr-passes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jr-passes)
[national-rail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/national-rail)
[nederlandse-spoorwegen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nederlandse-spoorwegen)
[shinkansen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shinkansen)
[sncf](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sncf)
[tatkal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tatkal)
[tgvair](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tgvair)
[thalys](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thalys)
[train-stations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/train-stations)
[trans-siberian](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trans-siberian)
[trenitalia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trenitalia)
[trenord](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trenord)
[via-rail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/via-rail)

Comment: I believe we now also have a [tag:train-stations] tag. In the 2.5 years since I proposed this I feel we have "zoomed into the fractal" enough now to warrant having these as separate tags. The only problem I see now is that our tag "trains" is equivalent to both the tags "aircraft" and "air-travel" where most of our questions tagged "trains" are actually about "rail travel". So while I no longer mind splitting up I still feel the tag should be renamed, but no longer to "rail" but "rail travel". WAIT now I'm confused. You're saying both "don't change" and "don't separate". \-:

Comment: What's "OTT"? By the way, while looking into this I found a worse mess. We have both [tag:metro] and [tag:subways] and they are not synonyms of each other but each a synonym of a different tag.

Comment: Too many synonyms??

Comment: It doesn't require dev assistance. It requires mod assistance. Which is easier to obtain. At least that is my understanding.

Comment: Really?! Is there a meta.SE topic on this? It sounds like a real problem.